# Run a ASP.Net webpage from IIS in a machine without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

this may be a simple question but until now I always created a web site with Visual Studio and ran it via Visual Studio. But now I have to run it in a computer that doesn't have Visual Studio. I'm guessing I have to install IIS but I don't know how to run that website. How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ASP.NET and IIS Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install IIS on that machine, then set the folder with the site in it as a Virtual Directory. IIS will handle everything else from there.

Assuming you set everything up correctly, you should be able to access the site like so:

http://localhost/whateveryourfolderis

Comment: To add to Steve's answer, if you need help installing IIS this link should help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782498%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you have to install iis 7 or higher version for run .net application if you use windows xp so you have to upgrade it with Service Pack 3 it provide iis 7 for .net application

after install IIS put you application in INITPUB dir in C: run in browser with http://localhost:80/applicationname

it working

Comment: To expand on user653116's answer, what version of IIS you need to install depends on the version of .Net that your application was written in. If it is .Net 3.5 or earlier, then you would be okay with installing II6, otherwise, you will need IIS7.

Just wanted to clarify those requirements. All that said, installing IIS7 is probably the wiser idea.